# How do I set all `transferFrom` calls to have a summary dispatch in certora?

Tags: certora

I have the following methods block:

```
methods {
  function transferFrom() external;
}
```

And I want to setup a function summary so that all `transferFrom` functions all always return 1. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard dispatch.

```js
methods {
  function _.transferFrom() external => ALWAYS(1);
}
```

Let me explain:

- `_.transferFrom`: The `_` means that *any contract that calls a `transferFrom() function will do the function summary.*
- `ALWAYS(1)`: Every single `transferFrom` will return the uint256 1 (as far as the prover is concerned)